# How change the bootstrap buttons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap.css changed the color of the button btn-primary in different states, but somehow able to hover, it stands only half. Where is it possible to fix? Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: open Firebug/Chrome, find a class to overlap.

Answer (score 13):

In the bootstrap.css, you able to change the color of button in the class `btn-primary` in different states. Let's see the following code:

```
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #3276b1;
  border-color: #285e8e;
}
```

So. you can change the color, background-color, and etc as you wish.

Comment: Boostrap 3 : Do not forget also the double pseudo class .btn-primary:active:focus otherwise the button will keep its original color on click

Comment: @bviale, please add more details or a sample

Answer (score 1):

working with Bootstrap buttons is very easy refer to [buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons).

also you can change their behavior by targeting the button class in the Bootstrap.css or in your custom.css file that override Bootstrap.css

**for example:**

1. you used button **default** or **primary** or any other button type.
2. search in your Bootstrap.css for class like **.btn-default** or **.btn-primary** or any other class **.btn-xxxx**.
3. you will have your button states ( hover, focus, active) change the value as you want like

*color:* ---> for the color of the font on the button.

*background-color:* ---> for the background color of the button,   and so on.

hope this help you , and if you need more help pleas upload a live code.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change css at main application level, the best way is to use http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 0):

> change class name...example:
>
> .btn-test {
>    color: #FF5733;
>    background-color: #800000;
>
> }
>
> .btn-test:hover {
>    color: #800000;
>    background-color: #FF5733;
>   }